# send attachment with mail function but my code is only sending file path

Tags: php, email

I want to send attachment with mail function but my code is only sending
file path please guide me whats the issue below is my code :

```
$contacts = explode(",", $to); array_walk($contacts, 'trim');

foreach($contacts as $contact)  {

    $tto = $contact; $headers = "From: De <info@xyz.com>" . "\r\n";

    $mailBody .= $attachment ;

    if (mail($tto,$subject,$mailBody,$headers)) {
        echo "SEND";
    } else {
        echo "NOT SEND"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer below code for send attachment using mail function.

```
<?PHP

$to = "user1432@gmail.com";
$subject = "Your password with attachment test";
$from = "admin@itservice.com";
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
  ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"1a2a3a\"";

$message .= "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
  ."--1a2a3a\r\n";

$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
  ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
  ."hey my <b>good</b> friend here is a picture of me"
  ."<p>Your password is : <span style='color:red'><b>User@1$#!</b></span></p> \r\n"
  ."--1a2a3a\r\n";

$file = file_get_contents("picture.jpg");

$message .= "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"picture.jpg\"\r\n"
  ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
  ."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"picture.jpg\"\r\n"
  ."\r\n"
  .chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
  ."--1a2a3a--";

// Send email

$success = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   if (!$success) {
  echo "Mail to " . $to . " failed .";
   }else {
  echo "Success : Mail was send to " . $to ;
   }

?>
```

You have to use `file_get_contents` method to attach file in mail fucntion.